# cardinality of fiber of a covering space

Tags: covering-spaces, fiber-bundles

On wikipedia, it says that every covering space is a fiber bundle. My understanding of a fiber bundle is that you have a topological space $F$ and $\pi:Y\to X$ surjective and for every $x\in X$, $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is homeomorphic to $F$. So each fiber has the same cardinality.

Now I know that if $X$ is connected, then every fiber has the same cardinality, but is this true for general $X$?

Comment: Obviously not. The disjoint union of any two covering map is also covering. But most of the times, $X$ is assumed to be (path-)connected.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true, since you could just take separate covering maps over disconnected parts which have fibers of different size.  For a really simple example, if $X$ and $Y$ are discrete spaces then *any* map $Y\to X$ is a covering map but the fibers of an arbitrary map certainly do not need to have the same cardinality.

(Here I do not require covering maps to be surjective, which is the better definition, but in any case the fibers of a surjective map do not have to have the same cardinality either.)

Comment: Why do you say it's better not to require covering maps to be surjective ? Doesn't the theory of covering spaces then break down ? (for instance  if you don't assume surjectivity, the universal cover doesn't have a map to all covers even for nice spaces )

Comment: @Max: The usual theory of covering spaces is only about _connected_ spaces and their _connected_ covers, and the empty space should not be considered connected, so you don't need to separately require surjectivity.  If you don't require connectedness, then the correct statement is that covering spaces correspond to functors from the fundamental groupoid to Set, and that requires you to allow non-surjective coverings.  When the base space is connected, this says covers correspond to $G$-sets where $G$ is the fundamental group, and this statement is cleaner if you allow the empty $G$-set!

Comment: In particular, the correct universal property of the universal cover of a connected space is that it maps uniquely to any cover _with a chosen basepoint_.  For the empty cover, there is no basepoint you can choose, so you get no maps.  (In terms of $G$-sets, the universal cover is the free $G$-set on one generator.)

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I had actually made a mistake while thinking about it (I was about to write "how about the inclusion of an open $U\to X$?" but realized that it was stupid). Yes of course I agree with you, my bad !